# How can I remove setBackgroundResource when new View is clicked?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a Horizontal Listview with a textview. When I click on a textview in the view, that particular textview gets a border.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.minute_listview, null);
        Typeface afBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AftenScreen-Bold.ttf");
        minuteText = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Button button = (Button) retval.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);
        minuteText.setText(dataObjects[position]);
        minuteText.setTypeface(afBold);

//THIS IS WHERE THE BORDER GETS SET
        minuteText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
            }
        });

        return retval;
    }
```

Now, how can I remove this border and set it on the next textview thats clicked?

Comment: you can always accept and upvote if it helps

Comment: I always do! But cant accept when the solution doesent hjelp me

Comment: Here you go! It did not work as I needed it to and I had to give it another approach. But by all means

Comment: no sir do not accept it, how did  you want it to work? and what was the result? so i see if i can help. Free feel not to accept i was just trying to give you a heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this it will give you a white background or a translucent one, in other words it has been removed

```
WhatEverView.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

okay full code

```
int pos -1;// default is -1, which means no one has altered it
// replicate this onclick listener logic
minuteText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(pos != -1){ // it is not -1 that means some1 has altered it                 
                parentView.findViewById(pos).
                      setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            // the above line searched for the view and changed the background
            }
            pos = v.getId(); // the id of the new view, keep doing it
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        }
    });
```

so use this for all onclick listeners you want that effect on

Does it fit your requirement?

Comment: But the View is always the same: v.

Comment: This might work but sorry if this is a stupid question, but how can I just create a View?

Comment: create a View? which view are you creating? we are not creating any view, we are just searching for a previously clicked view

Comment: My bad. I missunderstud. But pos has to be final to use it in the onClick() that means I cant set pos = v.getId();

Comment: omg, sorry i am writing an off head code, Sir, take it out of the getview method and make it a global variable to your base class,  or you can create a new `int` inside the onclick listener above the onclick method and asign it to the pos int. @user2927356 are you clear now or ?

Comment: @Ellts I had to go with the global to get it to work. Very nice! What I forgot to mention is that I want to change all the other views, not just the parent. Any clue of how I can do that?

Comment: you mean you want to change all views that when you click the background changes or you want to change all views when you click on the Textview? @user2927356

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
TextView ClicledTv ;//to save the clicked tv id
```

then

```
 minuteText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(Clickedtv!=null)
                clickedtv.setBackground(R.drawable.anotherOne);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
                clickedTv=minuteText;
            }
        });
```